# Adding negation to the time match of iptables. What does it mean?

Tags: command-line, networking, security, iptables

I want to allow access to traffic only from 07:00 to 15:00.

I want to use negation since I have other iptables rules.
Does using negation in the following exemple meet my requirements about time slot?

```
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time ! --timestart 07:00 --timestop 15:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

Your negation rule would probably work, but you might want to instead consider doing this as two rules separately rather than using a single negation rule (because sometimes they have problems or can be confusing when debugging your rulesets).

You may want to consider splitting this into two rules instead of using one negation rule:

```
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time --timestart 00:00 --timestop 07:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j DROP
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time --timestart 15:00 --timestop 23:59 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j DROP
```

That said, we can reduce the complexity of the rules greatly as well.  The defaults for `days` is "Every Day" so you don't have to define it, `timestart` defaults to 00:00, and `timestop` defaults to 23:59, so these two rules can be rewritten and simplified to:

```
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time --timestop 07:00 -j DROP
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time --timestart 15:00 -j DROP
```

Alternatively, we can do the *inverse* and do this instead:

```
iptables -A MYCHAIN -m time --timestart 07:00 --timestop 15:00 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MYCHAIN -j DROP
```

... and then any time outside this hits the DROP rule.  The only reason this might not be desirable is if you have other access control rules in place that also need adhered to, in which case use the previous suggestion I made.